# Golang and gqlgen with GitHub

Tags: go

I see this line of command in the gqlgen getting started page.

`go mod init github.com/[username]/gqlgen-todos`

why Golang is linked to GitHub?

In this case, is it necessary to really initiate the repo in my Github account? Will gqlgen or Golang automatically push the code to GitHub?

Comment: This might help you understand what it means [go mod](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules)

Comment: It's just the name of the module, and by extension the import path (prefix) for your package(s). There does not have to be a repository on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go has no links with github.

[Modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) allow you use any name you want as a package name, for example

`go mod init bestPackageEver`

Using VCS URLs are often used because of the convenience of working with a remote server:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/my/repo
go mod init github.com/my/repo
```

gqlgen uses github in docks just because their source code is hosed on github.

You can find more details in Russ Cox's [article](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/24301-versioned-go.md).